# Apple Push Notification Service - notification messages aren't sent to iphone device

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I constructed provider code with using C# and it was able to send notification messages to iphone devices successfully. But since yesterday, it hasn't worked. Also it seems to connect APNS successfully and send notification message. Unfortunately, no notification message is received by iphone device. I controlled internet connection and device token of iphone device. What else can I do? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I dont have enough rep to comment on the question so typing out answer - Please add more details and I will edit my answer.

Is this in a developer / testing environment and are you using an ad hoc profile to install the application on the iphone devices?
Did you check if the device token has changed and that you are using the new/ correct token in the C# code?

Do provide more details of your problem.

Comment: oh you poor thing, +1 for not having enough rep

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is no problem for now, it works. But I have no idea how it started to work, maybe restarting iphone device could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Crazywood, I don't have a solid answer for you but I can tell you I'm in the same boat as you. 
There are times when all my notifications go through and times when none of them seem to.

One guess is that not all notifications are sent. According to the docs, in **production** remote notifications are **not** guaranteed to be received by the client. My guess is that this is also the case for the sandbox.

-------- EDIT ------

I went through the trouble shooting list (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2010/tn2265.html) and came across this:

> The device may have lost its persistent connection to the push service and can't reconnect. Try quitting the app and relaunching it to see if registration completes the next time. (On iOS 4 and later on devices that support multitasking, you will need to force quit the app from the recents list.) If the registration does not complete, iOS has been unable to re-establish the persistent connection. You can troubleshoot this as described in the previous two sections.

I restarted the app and it made no difference. Then I rebooted my phone. That seemed to do the trick.